# Hibernate order by multiple values

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

There is `Event` entity with params: `id long` and `isActive boolean` the purpose is to sort it by `id desc` but `isActive` with value 1 should be in the top of the list and only after that will go 0 value(no mixed). Can I do this only with Hibernate query or at first create query `FROM Event event order by active desc` and then use java.util.Comparator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using JPQL/HQL only without sorting the results in Java:

```
FROM Event ORDER BY active DESC, id DESC
```

HQL and JPQL allow you to sort results by multiple fields, just like SQL. You can find more information about the usage of `ORDER BY` for instance in [Java EE docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbuf.html#bnbwd).

If you have data in database like this:

```
id  active
1   0
2   1
3   0
4   1
5   1
```

Then this is what will be returned by this query:

```
id  active
5   1
4   1
2   1
3   0
1   0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The result is as you said and I have tried it before  but it was bug in another place that why my view is not properly displayed and I thought it was wrong query.Thy!

Answer (score 1):

```
FROM Event event order by active desc, id desc
```